# What is rotate and no-rotate in sphinx search

Tags: sphinx

Can somebody explain me what is the difference between **rorate** and **no-rorate** options in **Sphinxsearch** indexing? I referred the Sphinx documentation, but I felt the explanation given there is bit hard for me to understand.

Answer (score 0):

What `indexer --rotate` does is it sends a HUP signal to the running searchd (it understands that from the process id specified in the file specified in `pid_file` in config you give it in `--config` or `-c`). If there's no running searchd no signal will be sent. If there's a running searchd, but you try to index w/o `--rotate` it will generate a warning.

The idea is:

- no running searchd: you just build a new index. All is
  straightforward.
- there's a running searchd and you index with
  `--rotate`: when your index is built its files' names get suffix
  `.new.` and the indexer sends a signal to the searchd. The searchd
  accepts the signal and replaces the existing index files with the new
  ones (with suffix `.new.`), it also does some other internal things
  and altogether it is called an index rotate.

Another way to rotate is to build your index in a new place and then call [RELOAD INDEX idx FROM](https://docs.manticoresearch.com/latest/singlehtml/index.html#document-sphinxql_reference/reload_index_syntax)